# NSArray convert to two numeric variables

Tags: ios, objective-c

there is such a dictionary

```
 [states setObject:@"60.050043,30.345783" forKey:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"Distance is %f km", (betweenDistance3 / 1000)] ];
```

The values of the dictionary are transferred to another view, and from the signification `setObject: @ "60.050043,30.345783"` get variable capital (`NSString`). I value this variable should be passed to `CLLocationCoordinate2DMake` (60.050043,30.345783); There can only be transferred numeric value two arguments. I take a variable capital, and thus share

```
       NSString* sourceString = capital;
NSArray* words = [ sourceString componentsSeparatedByString: @"," ];
```

But how do I convert an array into two variables of type nsnumber ?

Comment: You could start by actually reading the documentation for NSString.

Comment: Why don't use `NSValue`, which can easily translate coordinate into object and reverse.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One approach is to call `doubleValue` on each of the two `NSString`s in the `words` array, and make `NSNumber`s from them, like this:

```
NSNumber *first = [NSNumber numberWithDouble:[words[0] doubleValue]];
NSNumber *second = [NSNumber numberWithDouble:[words[1] doubleValue]];
```